# Why aren't my Powerline adapters working?

Tags: powerline-networking

Model: No. TL-PA4010KIT (they're TP-Link adapters)

Alright, so, I've had these adapters for about a year now. They were working perfectly until today. Today I got a new hard drive and installed Windows 7 Home Premium (64-bit) onto it. I connected the device back to my computer and installed Powerline Utility through the website and Utility says that the "local device is not connected" when all the lights are green.

I've tried updating the firmware (which didn't work due to it "not being connected"), unplugging and re-plugging both devices, redoing the pairing on them, restarting my computer. Nothing seems to work.

When I tried to find out why through Windows' Network Troubleshooter, it said that I didn't have the driver installed. Well, I've looked around and around, but I can't seem to find anything about a driver on the support page for the adapter or anywhere else.

If it matters, on my other hard drive I had Windows 7 Ultimate (64-bit).

I'd really like to know of any solutions because I can't keep using my phone to connect to the internet. Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely unrelated to the Powerline devices - it is much more likely the problem is the driver for your network card.

The TPLink kit should act as a "virtual switch" - and switches do not require Windows drivers.  What does require drivers, of-course, is the NIC itself.

I would try:
1.  Ensure the ethernet cables are correctly plugged in to the Powerline devices.
2.  Temporarily move your devices into the same room and get them working
    together without the Powerline.    Then move them back and plug them 
    back in to the Powerline.